# Notification to the end users about a newer version

Tags: qt, versioning, notifications

I am having an application that will be installed on various machines. Now if i have a newer version than the installed one, i need to inform the users that an update is available. An update that shows up in Mozilla Firefox about a newer version,similar to that. Is this possible to implement?? Or how those Firefox guys implementing that feature? My application has been implemented using Qt 4.4. But i guess this doesn't conform to a specific programming language. I have virtually no idea about implementing this so any ideas regarding this are welcome.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain your users care/want to be notified about updates? If updates are necessary then just update automatically without hassling the user. Firefox is a good example, it updates the next time it starts up.

Comment: Although it's often polite and good practice to *ask* the user before slapping the update on them, just in case they're busy and would prefer to defer...

Comment: @ Sam Post, But even Firefox asks whether to install the update or not. The same case for me too. The users can work with their current versions without any issues but still they need to be informed about the newer one..

Comment: How about providing a service / resource in your server that will tell you what the latest version is. THEN, you compare this value against the client version.

Comment: @ geff_chang, Ya, i guess that will do the trick. I can check for the version for every start up of my application and if required the user can be notified. Though i don't have an idea about how to implement this.

Comment: @geff, Seems like a bit overkill. It is sufficient (IMHO) to add simple php script which reads the modification date of the installation file. That's all for server part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need a web site page, like http://yourapp.com/version
and place version number in this page.

each time your app runs, check this page(quietly),
if found version > current version, then open a confirm window.